# Cycle two arrays in parallel

Tags: python

Cycle through two arrays in parallel by adding `:` between them during print

**Arrays**

```
NOME = ['CARLOS','JOAO','PEDRO']

IDADE ['30','25','22']
```

**GOAL**

```
CARLOS:30
JOAO:25
PEDRO:22
```

**SCRIPT**

```
rows = len(NOME)
for i in range(rows):
    print(str(NOME[i]+":"+IDADE))
```

**ERROR**

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: You missed taking indexed value from second array `NOME[i]+":"+IDADE` should be `NOME[i]+":"+IDADE[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

rows = len(NOME)
for i in range(rows):
    print(str(NOME[i]+":"+IDADE[i]))